# match string beginning with phrase but not ending with another phrase

Tags: regex

I have a character vector as below :

```
"sit", "situation", "situat", "lettuce", "situationabcd"
```

I'd like to subset "sit", "situation" and "situat". In fact, I'd like to subset all strings that begins with "sit" but not the ones ending with "abcd".

I tried  `"^(?!.*abcd$).*$"`
but this one subsets `"lettuce"` as well.

Comment: Try `^(?!.*abcd$).*sit.*$`

Comment: I started with this one and started playing and came up with: `^sit(?!.*abcd$)`.  I'm not getting with the `sit.*` in the end is getting the same result as mine..

Comment: So, does anything work? Where are you using the patterns?

Comment: Yours and the one I mentioned worked.  I'm using in R with the package stringr.  For reproducibility my vector is: `x <- c("sit", "situation", "situat", "lettuce", "situationabcd")`.  I subset with: `str_subset(x, "^sit(?!.*abcd$)")`.  The outcome is as desired.

Comment: Then you may accept the answer below, ICU regex in stringr supports all kinds of lookarounds well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach it by using negative lookbehind against the end-of-string object (`$`).

Here an example in Javascript:

```
var str = [ "sit", "situation", "situat", "lettuce", "situationabcd" ];

var expr = /^sit.*?$(?<!abcd)/;

console.log (str.filter(x=>x.match(expr)));
// Outputs: [ 'sit', 'situation', 'situat' ]
```

**Edit:**

Here pre-ES2018 javascript solution:

```
var str = [ "sit", "situation", "situat", "lettuce", "situationabcd" ];

console.log (
    str
        .filter(x=>x.match(/^sit/))
        .filter(x=>!x.match(/abcd$/))
);
// Outputs: [ 'sit', 'situation', 'situat' ]
```

In fact this is the original solution I thought to provide but I declined primarily because that the original question asks for single regular expression and don't say if can be approached by more than one and/or in any programming language even javascript.

But, in fact, this is a better solution if you are able to apply two regular expressons for two reasons:

- Firstly, lookahead and lookbehind are expensive in all regular expression implementations (ones much more than others but expensive in all cases).
- ...and because approaching this behaviour avoiding negative lookbehind will be hard and I figure out the solution will be expensive anyway (because "abcd" character position can overlap or not whith the initial "sit" initial substring).

Comment: yes, but there is no lookbehind available in js regex. could use `^sit(?!.*?abcd$).*$` instead.

Comment: @bobblebubble You may use variable width lookbehind in Chrome now.

Comment: In ES2018 it is (in fact I ran that example in NodeJS obtaining the result you see in the comment. I didn't know you need to run it in javascript (and there is no such tag). But, in this case I would suggest to simply apply two expressions: one for the beginning and one for the ending.

Comment: However I'd also think of using a lookbehind at first if the question is regex flavor independent. The non-greedy quantifier might cause a few more steps another idea if possessive quantifiers are available would be `^sit.*+(?<!abcd)` but that just mentioned for interest.

Comment: @bitifet you patter will match something like situationabc or situationab

Comment: @Abdo "situationabc" and "situationab" doesn't end in "abcd", so should match.

Comment: @bobblebubble: I just edited my answer adding pre-ES2018 approach (which is, in fact, the original solution I were thinking to provide).